# I installed Magento, logged in admin panel. But if I press Edit product in admin menu Catalog ---> Manage Products menu, I get error like this:

Tags: magento

I installed Magento, logged in admin panel. But if I press Edit product in admin menu Catalog ---> Manage Products menu, I get error like this:

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 225721484146

That error log record number looks like a link, but pressing it nothing happens.

So actually I can only open  menu Catalog ---> Manage Products in admin panel, but can't Edit anything here.

What could be wrong? I installed the newest Magento version (Magento ver. 1.9.0.1).

I tried to sovle my problem in the doing like this bellow mentioned, even it could not work,

1) Open Magento root directory and create tmp folder.

2) Set directory permissions to 777 or 755

3) Open

```
“lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php“, and locate the following code protected $_options = array( ‘cache_dir’ => null, replace with protected $_options = array( ‘cache_dir’ => ‘tmp/’,
```

or

1)Navigate to the "errors" folder.
2)Change local.xml.sample to local.xml
3)You should now see a new list of crazy errors all over the Magento page - this is okay.
4)Open `magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php` and look for:

```
protected $_options = array('cache_dir' => 'null',
```

Change it to:

```
 protected $_options = array('cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
```

5)Save it.

6)Now the final step is to go create a tmp folder in the root Magento folder.

7)That's it.

In Above both are i tried but its note working,
please any one help me...

Comment: That number is a file that exists in var/report. Go open it with an SCP/SFTP client and read the contents.

Comment: Hi firends i got answer and fixed that problem....

Answer (score 1):

I got answer, its working perfectly.....

steps:

1. Go to Magento root folder where you create your Magento project folder.
2. Locate Error folder and find  local.xml.sample file and rename  local.xml.

importent:

keep a copy of new file as local.xml.sample.

Now your error folder must have two files:

local.xml.sample file and rename  local.xml.

3. Now clear flush catch and restart your Magento Admin.
4. Add your new product and edit your product...its perfectly working

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: This means you didn't actually "install" Magento, you just copied it to the destination folder otherwise that file would have been created.

Comment: Sorry,After we installed Magento we only having in Error folder   local.xml.sample file only but we have have to copy and rename our file as  local.xml, please be see in your folder, then you can understand.